# Htaccess rule /a/b/c to a=&b=&c=

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect with HTACCESS:
`http://www.domain.com/emailreader/10/15/abc`

to

`http://www.domain.com/emailreader.php?a=10&b=15&c=abc`

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(emailreader)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?a=$2&b=$3&c=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this

```
RewriteRule ^emailreader/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ /emailreader.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC,L]
```